# Partial least square different maximization programs

Tags: covariance-matrix, partial-least-squares

PLS regression is a regression method based based on latent variables in order to handle collinearity or violation of full rank assumption in linear regression.
Latent variables called components are computed one after another till results are considered good enough.
I'm actually looking at the simplest PLS method with only 1 response variable :

Let $X (n,m)$ denote an input matrix of $n$ observations and $m$ variables and $y (n,1)$ a target matrix.

In order to compute the first component ($t_1 = Xw_1$), we need to find the first weigth vector noted $w_1 (m,1)$ that maximizes a criteria. I found in the litterature two ways of writing the program :

$$\text{max } cov(Xw_1,y) = \text{max } w_{1}^{\intercal}X^{\intercal}y$$ 
$$ \text{s/t } w_{1}^{\intercal}w_1 = 1 $$

The second is similar but it maximizes the square of covariance :
$$\text{max } cov^{2}(Xw_1,y) = \text{max } w_{1}^{\intercal}X^{\intercal}yy^{\intercal}Xw_1$$ 
$$ \text{s/t } w_{1}^{\intercal}w_1 = 1 $$

I found in the litterature that both methods yield the same results so I want to know why it is the case as the way of getting $w_1$ is different : eigen decomposition for example nedded in the second program.

Comment: Are you comparing NIPALS and SIMPLS algorithms?